# WPF MVVM Model Link Button

Tags: wpf

I am using MVVM Model with wpf and I added link of user control on main window as below -

```
<mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks >
 <mui:Link DisplayName="Home" Source="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
    <mui:Link DisplayName="Sync Data" Source="/Views/SyncData.xaml" />
    <mui:Link DisplayName="Help" Source="http://www.nextolive.com" />
    <mui:Link DisplayName="Sign out" Source="/Views/Login.xaml"  />
</mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
```

When we click on Link then first time page is refreshed but when click next time page does not refreshed but loaded with old Data.

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: No code for link.When you click on Link automatically redirected in another page but no fired constructor of view model.

Comment: Please provide any body solution of this question very fast ,your time is start now

Comment: any body  will be provide answer of this question